# PostgreSql Traverse through an array to fetch results in multiple rows under same column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have JSON data as follows:

```
"group_nw4qu40":[
{"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"11"},
{"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"0"},
{"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"0"},
{"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"1"},
{"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"1"}]
```

My task is to Traverse though the Array within an array to fetch the "Special_Characteristic" of each individual member and create a table having these values in Multiple Rows under same column.

I tried using this query but, it fetches me values in multiple columns which is incorrect for me.

```
select id AS id, (json->'group_nw4qu40'->>0)::json->>'group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics' AS value_of_special_characteristic from public.logger_instance where id = 5215
```

Please help me get these values in  multiple Rows under same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()` or `json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), e.g.:

```
with the_data (json) as (
    values (
        '{"group_nw4qu40":[
        {"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"11"},
        {"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"0"},
        {"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"0"},
        {"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"1"},
        {"group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics":"1"}]}'::jsonb)
    )
select e->>'group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics' value_of_special_characteristic
from the_data, jsonb_array_elements(json->'group_nw4qu40') e

 value_of_special_characteristic 
---------------------------------
 11
 0
 0
 1
 1
(5 rows)
```

Your actual query should look like this:

```
select id, e->>'group_nw4qu40/Special_Characteristics' value_of_special_characteristic
from public.logger_instance, jsonb_array_elements(json->'group_nw4qu40') e 
where id = 5215;
```